# Electrical: Replace light switch with smart switch, odd wiring question

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, attic, gable

I have a very simple switch attached to my attic fan.  Between the switch and the fan is a temperature sensor that will only trigger the fan when the attic is hot enough.

I’d like to replace the switch with a WiFi-connected light switch so I can easily turn it off and on (or setup schedules for the matter).

The problem is, the wiring is very very simple, and most smart switches seem to require a more complete setup.  Am I out of luck? Or can I use this wiring with a switch that doesn’t require a neutral?

[image: wires]
[image: switch]

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows the inside of the box more clearly please?

Comment: There are many WiFi enabled smart devices that will work without a neutral. However, this isn't a shopping recommendation service, so you're on your own to pick one that will work with your system, allows for or denies general internet access to the switch, etc. Note that WiFi-enabled [IoT.se] devices rarely have decent security on them and thus expose your entire home network to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

2 wire switches like this are usually in Series with a thermal element like a adjustable bimetallic contact with the element in the attic.

Jumping the actual thermostat out in the attic would be the first step.
Once the actual device is jumpered then the switch would. Intros the fan.

I have found smart devices that could now be put in place with the switch and a thermister or a thermocouple is wired up to the attic location.

A thermister is a device that changes resistance with temperature
A thermocouple the voltage changes as the temperature changes
The smart device uses a small amount power from the line and no neutral is available in this case but there are smart devices that can work once the existing device most probably a adjustable bimetallic contact is bypassed or jumpered.